# Getting SQL Exception when trying to get the last auto-incremented value

Tags: java, mysql

I've been trying everything, nothing is working, I'm new to mysql and databases and I want to get the last auto-incremented id (primary key) (`user_id`) from a table, from java. So this: `SELECT MAX(user_id) FROM database_user;` works fine in mysql, I got that, but why can't I get the same thing from java??

```
PreparedStatement st = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT MAX(user_id) from database_user");
st.executeUpdate();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
int uid = rs.getInt(1);
System.out.println(uid);
```

This gives me `java.sql.SQLException: (conn=213) the given SQL statement produces an unexpected ResultSet object`

This isn't the only thing I tried, it's just the last one so far. If anyone could just shed some light I would greatly appreaciate it.

Comment: What's the reason for both the `st.executeUpdate();` and `st.executeQuery();`? And which of these lines throws the Exception?

Comment: @f1sh ```st.executeUpdate()``` produced the exception, I removed it and called ```rs.next()```, it works fine now, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `rs.next();` between executing the query and fetching from the result set.  This is needed, to move the result set to the first row.

You also shouldn't have `st.executeUpdate()`.  Just executing once is enough.

Comment: Doesn't that case have a specific Exception message?

Comment: Thanks @f1sh - noticed one error but not the other till you pointed it out.